# Where is Redis key's expiry data stored?

Tags: redis

When we set an expiry on any Redis key, where is that information stored? Is it stored in RDB/AOF file? Or is there some other meta-data file that Redis maintains for storing the TTLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In memory, Redis saves expiration info as a dict, i.e. a hash. Dict's key is Redis key, and value is the expire time in milliseconds.

When dumping data into RDB or AOF file, Redis also saves expiration info into the file. So that it can recover the expiration info when reloading.

With RDB file, Redis saves expire time with EXPIRETIME type in binary format. With AOF, Redis save expire time as a `PEXPIREAT` command. So that when reloading AOF file, Redis simply run the `PEXPIREAT` command to recover expiration info.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just curious, where can I get all these low level details? Documentation or is  there a good book or oher resource? @for_stack

Comment: If you want to know the low level details, you have to read the source code, i.e. db.c and aof.c files.